# Tkinter, Новое окно: Как мне сделать так чтоб не создавалось новое окно по нажатию на кнопку если это окно уже открыто?

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть скрипт который по нажатию на кнопку создает новое окно. 
Как мне сделать так чтоб не создавалось новое окно по нажатию на кнопку если это окно уже открыто?
Вот код:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('700x700')
root.title('Root')

def new_window(event):
    window = Toplevel(root)

lab = Label(root, text='Press here')
but = Button(root, text='Ok')
but.bind('<Button->', new_window)

lab.pack()
but.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/525874/

Answer (score 1):

Можно `withdraw()`/`deiconify()` вместо создания/разрушения окна использовать.

Comment: А можно не много подробнее у меня просто такой же вопрос появился

Comment: @KuzminAlexey методы сворачивают/разворачивают окно.  Попробуйте `root.withdraw()`, а потом `root.deiconify()` через какое-то время.